# Hiding rule- do the arguments/return type have to be the same?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a few questions/a general question regarding hiding?

A base class has a function: f() a derived class now declares virtual f()

What happens if the derived function is const? Does this not hide?

What about if the return types are different?

The parameters are different?

One is static and the other not?

Just wondering which of these differences between the two functions cause hiding/do not cause hiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding is about names, not signatures.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.

Hiding refers to the idea that if you override a base class function in a derived class then in that derived class the original base class method that you defined will be hidden. -- That said, if you need to access your definition of the function from the base class then you'd need to have this in your code to it is NOT hidden :

```
using baseClass::functionName();
```

**Const** - if you define a function twice once with const another without const  they are different. Scott Mayers book effective c++ contains an excellent chapter explaining const and non const-ness, I suggest you read it for a thorough understanding.

Your can not over-ride a function by having different return types, it will probably give compile time error stating its ambiguous - test it out, to make sure.

You CAN however overload a function by having different argument list, that is how one would overload a function.

If you're confused between over-ride and over-load - then I suggest you also read up on that. In a nutshell, overload is when you have two functions in the same scope with different argument lists, where as override is when you redefine a base class virtual function in a derived class with the same argument list.